# Unity transform.Rotate GetKeyDown and dont rotate again if facing direction?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hello super new to c# and Unity. I have an empty game object as a child of my player. I have it set up so that when I press my left or right direction buttons the empty rotates with my player using a very short script on the empty object itself. This is for prefab shooting. I was wonder how to make it so if I push the directional button again and I am already facing said direction it dosnt just rotate 180 degrees again. Thank you.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);   
}
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D ))
            transform.Rotate(0f, -180f, 0f);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You can simply add the script to the empty game object, too.

Comment: I have it on the empty game object. The issue is when I press a to turn left and have the empty which is the origin point for my arrow if I press a again it rotates 180 to the right and I start shooting to the right while my character is facing left still.

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you that this will only work with 2 directions

```
   public class HELPING : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isFacing;

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && isFacing)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
        isFacing = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && isFacing == false)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, -180f, 0f);
        isFacing = true;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error Use of unassigned local variable 'isFacing' on line 
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && isFacing){

but not the others, sorry again I am only a couple weeks into unity and c#

Comment: Okey, I fixed it you can now copy and paste again, the problems were that I put (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D and I didn't close the parenthesis and bool isFacing has to be declared before everything (DO NOT COPY THE PART OF PUBLIC CLASS HELPING, NOR THE CLOSING BRACKET)